# Console outputs System.int32[] when i try to convert string to int

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, int

I am trying to output a few numbers that are in the same line as a string by converting them from string to int im using split and trying to convert for first time and the output is system.int32[]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Websites = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int sectok = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] webnamearray = new string[Websites];
        int[] persums = new int[Websites];
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        string datainput = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < Websites; i++)
        {
            datainput = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] split = datainput.Split(' ');
            webnamearray[i] = (split[0]);
            one = int.Parse(split[1]);
            two = int.Parse(split[2]);
            persums[i] = one * two;
            Console.WriteLine(persums);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Websites;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webnamearray[i]);
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging#howtodebug (didn't downvote but if you don't learn how to debug your code you're going to attract them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
Console.WriteLine(persums);
```

which is an array of integers, that explains why you see that in your output.

I think instead your desired output is (which is your value that you just created):

```
Console.WriteLine(persums[i]);
```

and instead of if you want to place this information with the names change your last loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Websites;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(webnamearray[i] + " " + persums[i]);
}
```